# Elegant way to extract specific text from between HTML nodes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, dom, greasemonkey

From the following string I need the dynamically changing "6.903" number to make calculation with.

Is there some regular expression or some jQuery trick to do that easily or elegantly?

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="" id="buddyTrigger">
38.760&nbsp;<img border="0" align="absmiddle" alt="Arany" src="/img/symbols/res2.gif">
&nbsp;&nbsp;5&nbsp;<img border="0" align="absmiddle" alt="Pokolkristály" src="/img/symbols/res3.gif">
&nbsp;&nbsp;220&nbsp;<img border="0" align="absmiddle" alt="Szilánk" src="/img/symbols/res_splinters.png">
&nbsp;&nbsp;91&nbsp;/&nbsp;125&nbsp;<img border="0" align="absmiddle" alt="Akciópont" src="/img/symbols/ap.gif">
&nbsp;&nbsp;6.903&nbsp;/&nbsp;82.100&nbsp;<img border="0" align="absmiddle" alt="Életerő" src="/img/symbols/herz.png">
&nbsp;&nbsp;<img border="0" align="absmiddle" alt="Szint" src="/img/symbols/level.gif">&nbsp;41    &nbsp;&nbsp;
<img border="0" align="absmiddle" alt="Harci érték" src="/img/symbols/fightvalue.gif">&nbsp;878</a>
```

---

Here is my code as lenghty solution, can I simplify somehow?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dataIn=$('#infobar div.gold').html();
    var dataPrep2Split=dataIn.replace(/<img(.*)>/g,';');
    var dataSplit=dataPrep2Split.split(';');
    var myData2Int=parseInt(dataSplit[18].replace('.',''));
    if(myData2Int<=10000) {
        $('#player').find('button.btn').remove();
        var putBack=dataIn.replace(dataSplit[18],'<span class="newmessage">'+dataSplit[18]+'</span>');
        $('#infobar div.gold').html(putBack);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DOM methods; replacing things using `.html()` often breaks page features. Also, that regex is liable to break with the smallest change.

You're trying to grab the *Life* value right?  And that ends with the `<img>` with `alt="Életero"`.

So that text node is (based on the Q code):

```
var lifeValTxtNd    = $("#buddyTrigger img[alt='Életero']")[0].previousSibling;
```

And this gets `6903` from the contents like `6.903 / 82.100`:

```
var lifeVal         = $.trim (lifeValTxtNd.nodeValue)
                    .replace (/^\s*(\d*)\.?(\d+)\s*\/.+$/, "$1$2")
                    ;
lifeVal             = parseInt (lifeVal, 10);
```

Then to wrap that section in a span use:

```
$("#buddyTrigger img[alt='Életero']").before (
    '<span class="newmessage">' + lifeValTxtNd.nodeValue + '</span>'
);

lifeValTxtNd.parentNode.removeChild (lifeValTxtNd);
```

---

---

Doing it this way:

1. Won't break any event listeners on the page.
2. Is less susceptible to changes in the page layout/content.
3. Is easier to understand and maintain.
4. Will run faster, if performance is a factor.

Comment: Thank youn, now I know what are siblings :)